# Vim text editor running inside Anaconda Navigator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I was hoping...is it possible to use Vim inside Anaconda Navigator/Jupiter Lab instead of the text editor they provide?
To be more specific: regarding the option (create a new text file) can you create it/edit with Vim inside (Anaconda Navigator/Jupiter Lab), can you open text files?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use Vim inside Anaconda Navigator/Jupiter Lab if you create a terminal and run it there.

You can also set the default text editor for creating text files to Vim.

[Setting path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq4E5.png)